# how to get the distance from google, per country

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For example the route between Koln, Germany and Zeebrugge, Belgium.
Using google I can get the total distance between these 2 citys, but what I really need is the distance per country.

In this example I need the distance from:
1. Koln, Germany until the border with Netherlands
2. border with Netherlands until the border with Belgium
3. border with Belgium until Zeebrugge, Belgium

This because you drive thru Germany, than thru the Netherlands and finally thru Belgium.

if the total distance would be 430 km (wrong number, just an example) then I need something like
1. Germany 200 km
2. Netherlands 50 km
3. Belgium 180 km

Is this possible from a c# winforms application ?
And if so, how ?

Answer (score 1):

While you can set the `origin` and `destination` of the country itself when you call the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro), it won't be as detailed as what you wanted. Take for example the countries you specified

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Germany&destinations=Belgium
```

Since the default mode is `bicycle` (along with other default parameters) it will give out the total distance from the countries (which we don't know specifically points at) using that transportation mode

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Belgium" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Germany" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "482 km",
              "value" : 481983
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "4 days 4 hours",
              "value" : 360211
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Checked for other Google APIs but this seems to be the nearest you'll get.